# Paste data together in bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

I show you an example what I need to do with my data. I have two text files separated by tab.

```
cat in1.tsv

111 A B C
111 D E F
111 G H I
222 A B C
333 A B C
333 D E F
```

This table can have about thousands of rows. Number of columns is less than 100. First column can have repeated vaules (like 111 and 333).

```
cat in2.tsv

111 a b c 
222 a b c 
333 d e f
```

In this file are appear values in column 1 only once. I need to merge those two files according its first column match.

```
cat output.tsv

111 A B C 111 a b c
111 D E F 111 a b c
111 G H I 111 a b c
222 A B C 222 a b c 
333 A B C 333 d e f
333 D E F 333 d e f
```

My solution works if the size of matrix are the same:

```
paste  <(sort in1.tsv) <(sort in2.tsv) > output.tsv
```

I am appreciate any help in awk, bash or another programs that works fast for lot of rows.

Comment: This is something that looks solvable by using pandas module in Python or R. And if you need scaling, perhaps move onto Dask (another Python library).

Comment: thank you for comment. I was thinking first to use some awk or bash solution, because I am not very familiar with python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Awk` to the rescue!

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}FNR==NR{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) map[$1]=(map[$1] FS $i); next}$1 in map{print $0,$1,map[$1]}' in2.tsv in1.tsv
```

produces the output in the tab-separated format as you expected. Remove the `OFS="\t"` if you don't want the o/p tab separation.

As far as the logic, create a map containing the values per column 1 on `in2.csv` into a hash-map `map[]` and then on `in1.csv` pick those lines containing `$1` same as from the map formed and print the line contents.

Comment: Thank you Inian - this is very nice solution!

Comment: I am testing your script, it works, but always it put empty row - for example: 111 A B C 111 EMPTY a b c.. It is normal?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `bash` approach:

First let's sort each file:

```
LC_ALL=C sort init1.tsv -S75% -t$'\t' -k1,1 > init1.tsv.sorted

LC_ALL=C sort init2.tsv -S75% -t$'\t' -k1,1 > init2.tsv.sorted
```

Then instead of `pasting` lets `join` them by the first column,

```
join init1.tsv.sorted init2.tsv.sorted -1 1 -2 2 -t$'\t'
```

If you need a specific sort of join, this seems like a left outer join, then I would do this:

```
join init1.tsv.sorted init2.tsv.sorted -1 1 -2 2 -t$'\t' -a1
```

A quick note, `-S` specifies how much RAM you want to use, the faster you want this operation to go, the more you should use.

Comment: Nice solution thank you. Could you please explain first operation of sort - LC_ALL=C??

Comment: it over rides all local settings forcing output to be in the default language. also I believe it forces sorting to be bitwise.

Answer (score 2):

The [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) command seems to almost do what you want:

```
$ join in1.tsv in2.tsv
111 A B C a b c
111 D E F a b c
111 G H I a b c
222 A B C a b c
333 A B C d e f
333 D E F d e f
```

Default behavior is to join lines based on first column with whitespace as delimiter. Using the format option `-o` gives us the same result. Sorting is also required as Dmitry Polonskiy says in the comments:

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(sort in1.tsv) <(sort in2.tsv)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you join is very useful. In case data are unsorted, do I need to sort data?

Comment: yes, join will not work unless both files are sorted first

Answer (score 2):

In Python, not relying on the files being sorted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("in1.tsv") as in1, open("in2.tsv") as in2:
    d = {line.split()[0]: line for line in in2}
    for line in in1:
        print(line.strip(), d[line.split()[0]], sep="\t", end="")
```

This basically creates a mapping from values of the first column to lines of  `in2.tsv`, then loops over the lines of `in1.tsv` and combines them with the corresponding lines of `in2.tsv` using the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Would be possible to run this form terminal like python your_solution.py int1.tsv int2.tsv ? Sorry maybe for silly question.

Comment: The filenames in the example are hardcoded. If you want to pass parameters, then use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.argv) instead.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r 's#^(\S+)\s.*#/^\1/s/$/ &/#' file2 | sed -f - file
```

Create a sed script from the second file. This script consists of a regexp that when matched appends the matched record from the second file to matched record from the first.